# Deployment fail with build pack which is not located at cloudfoundry

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am learning about custom build packs in Bluemix, I have downloaded the sample code coming with the PHP web app and try to push it back using the `cf` cli tool.

The thing is that I get errors whenever I am not using the buildpack which is not located at the cloudfoundry site:

The line I write is:

```
cf push testPHPbuild -b <path to the build pack>
```

The following links works without a problem:

> https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack

While those two links fail:

> https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php
>
> git://github.com/antonpuz/phpbuildpack.git

The last one is copy of the PHP buildpack on cloudfoundry I made.
The error I receive is:

```
FAILED Server error, status code: 400, error code: 170004, message: App staging failed in the buildpack compile phase
```

Any suggestions?

The log:
4213889 app_id:5196da19-69b9-4db3-abdc-c9219e919688
2015-05-05T15:29:32.07+0300 [App/0]      OUT 12:29:32 httpd   | [Tue May 05 12:2
9:32.064316 2015] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 49:tid 139958308275968] [client 159.8.
128.13:57637] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, u
nexpected '$conn' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';' in /home/vcap/app/htdocs/in
dex.php on line 16\n'
2015-05-05T15:29:32.07+0300 [App/0]      OUT 12:29:32 httpd   | 159.8.128.13 - -
 [05/May/2015:12:29:32 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 - vcap_request_id=4685e9de-69
d4-42d9-4c95-6d0c985ca9c7 peer_addr=159.8.128.13
2015-05-05T16:00:15.19+0300 [API/5]      OUT Updated app with guid 5196da19-69b9
-4db3-abdc-c9219e919688 ({"name"=>"testPHPbuild", "instances"=>1, "memory"=>128,
 "disk_quota"=>1024, "buildpack"=>"https://github.com/dmikusa-pivotal/cf-php-bui
ld-pack", "environment_json"=>"PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN"})
2015-05-05T16:00:24.81+0300 [API/5]      OUT Updated app with guid 5196da19-69b9
-4db3-abdc-c9219e919688 ({"state"=>"STOPPED"})
2015-05-05T16:00:24.93+0300 [App/0]      ERR
2015-05-05T16:00:26.05+0300 [DEA/58]     OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) wit
h guid 5196da19-69b9-4db3-abdc-c9219e919688
2015-05-05T16:00:26.05+0300 [DEA/58]     OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with
 guid 5196da19-69b9-4db3-abdc-c9219e919688
2015-05-05T16:00:26.85+0300 [DEA/79]     OUT Got staging request for app with id
 5196da19-69b9-4db3-abdc-c9219e919688
2015-05-05T16:00:32.82+0300 [API/4]      OUT Updated app with guid 5196da19-69b9
-4db3-abdc-c9219e919688 ({"state"=>"STARTED"})
2015-05-05T16:00:32.94+0300 [STG/79]     OUT -----> Downloaded app package (20K)

2015-05-05T16:00:33.29+0300 [STG/79]     OUT -----> Downloaded app buildpack cac
he (7.7M)
2015-05-05T16:00:33.40+0300 [STG/0]      ERR     Cloning into '/tmp/buildpacks/c
f-php-build-pack'...
2015-05-05T16:00:35.77+0300 [STG/0]      OUT     Submodule 'compile-extensions'
(https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/compile-extensions) registered for pa
th 'compile-extensions'
2015-05-05T16:00:35.83+0300 [STG/0]      ERR Cloning into 'compile-extensions'..
.
2015-05-05T16:00:36.85+0300 [STG/0]      OUT Submodule path 'compile-extensions'
: checked out '8d4d16790032fc1ac34eb831478d96087ad659ad'
2015-05-05T16:00:37.07+0300 [STG/0]      OUT -------> Buildpack version 3.2.0
2015-05-05T16:00:38.56+0300 [STG/0]      OUT Installing HTTPD
2015-05-05T16:00:39.10+0300 [STG/0]      ERR   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Av
erage Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
2015-05-05T16:00:39.10+0300 [STG/0]      ERR                                  Dl
oad  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1329k  100 1329k    0     0   923k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 1231k
2015-05-05T16:00:40.19+0300 [STG/0]      OUT Downloaded [https://pivotal-buildpa
cks.s3.amazonaws.com/php/binaries/lucid/httpd/2.4.12/httpd-2.4.12.tar.gz] to [/t
mp]
2015-05-05T16:00:40.76+0300 [STG/0]      ERR   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Av
erage Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
2015-05-05T16:00:40.76+0300 [STG/0]      ERR                                  Dl
oad  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 12713  100 12713    0     0  23469      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 54797
2015-05-05T16:00:41.00+0300 [STG/0]      OUT Downloaded [https://pivotal-buildpa
cks.s3.amazonaws.com/php/binaries/lucid/httpd/2.4.12/httpd-mod_unixd-2.4.12.tar.
gz] to [/tmp]
2015-05-05T16:00:41.64+0300 [STG/0]      ERR   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Av
erage Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
2015-05-05T16:00:41.64+0300 [STG/0]      ERR                                  Dl
oad  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 18038  100 18038    0     0  26575      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 72152
2015-05-05T16:00:41.90+0300 [STG/0]      OUT Downloaded [https://pivotal-buildpa
cks.s3.amazonaws.com/php/binaries/lucid/httpd/2.4.12/httpd-mod_setenvif-2.4.12.t
ar.gz] to [/tmp]
2015-05-05T16:00:42.35+0300 [STG/0]      ERR   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Av
erage Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
2015-05-05T16:00:42.35+0300 [STG/0]      ERR                                  Dl
oad  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  112k  100  112k    0     0   126k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  172k
2015-05-05T16:00:43.01+0300 [STG/0]      OUT Downloaded [https://pivotal-buildpa
cks.s3.amazonaws.com/php/binaries/lucid/httpd/2.4.12/httpd-mod_proxy-2.4.12.tar.
gz] to [/tmp]
2015-05-05T16:00:43.47+0300 [STG/0]      ERR   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Av
erage Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
2015-05-05T16:00:43.47+0300 [STG/0]      ERR                                  Dl
oad  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 15756  100 15756    0     0  41530      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  109k
2015-05-05T16:00:43.62+0300 [STG/0]      OUT Downloaded [https://pivotal-buildpa
cks.s3.amazonaws.com/php/binaries/lucid/httpd/2.4.12/httpd-mod_dir-2.4.12.tar.gz
] to [/tmp]
2015-05-05T16:00:44.20+0300 [STG/0]      ERR   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Av
erage Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
2015-05-05T16:00:44.20+0300 [STG/0]      ERR                                  Dl
oad  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 18801  100 18801    0     0  33735      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  100k
2015-05-05T16:00:44.39+0300 [STG/0]      OUT Downloaded [https://pivotal-buildpa
cks.s3.amazonaws.com/php/binaries/lucid/httpd/2.4.12/httpd-mod_reqtimeout-2.4.12
.tar.gz] to [/tmp]
2015-05-05T16:00:44.85+0300 [STG/0]      ERR   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Av
erage Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
2015-05-05T16:00:44.85+0300 [STG/0]      ERR                                  Dl
oad  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 35498  100 35498    0     0  86189      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  198k
2015-05-05T16:00:45.04+0300 [STG/0]      OUT Downloaded [https://pivotal-buildpa
cks.s3.amazonaws.com/php/binaries/lucid/httpd/2.4.12/httpd-mod_log_config-2.4.12
.tar.gz] to [/tmp]
2015-05-05T16:00:45.51+0300 [STG/0]      ERR   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Av
erage Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
2015-05-05T16:00:45.51+0300 [STG/0]      ERR                                  Dl
oad  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 24977  100 24977    0     0  60204      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  135k
2015-05-05T16:00:45.70+0300 [STG/0]      OUT Downloaded [https://pivotal-buildpa
cks.s3.amazonaws.com/php/binaries/lucid/httpd/2.4.12/httpd-mod_authz_core-2.4.12
.tar.gz] to [/tmp]
2015-05-05T16:00:46.18+0300 [STG/0]      ERR   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Av
erage Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
2015-05-05T16:00:46.18+0300 [STG/0]      ERR                                  Dl
oad  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 22249  100 22249    0     0  50441      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  108k
2015-05-05T16:00:46.40+0300 [STG/0]      OUT Downloaded [https://pivotal-buildpa
cks.s3.amazonaws.com/php/binaries/lucid/httpd/2.4.12/httpd-mod_mime-2.4.12.tar.g
z] to [/tmp]
2015-05-05T16:00:46.91+0300 [STG/0]      ERR   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Av
erage Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
2015-05-05T16:00:46.91+0300 [STG/0]      ERR                                  Dl
oad  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 27931  100 27931    0     0  42610      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 82150
2015-05-05T16:00:47.27+0300 [STG/0]      OUT Downloaded [https://pivotal-buildpa
cks.s3.amazonaws.com/php/binaries/lucid/httpd/2.4.12/httpd-mod_proxy_fcgi-2.4.12
.tar.gz] to [/tmp]
2015-05-05T16:00:47.77+0300 [STG/0]      ERR   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Av
erage Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
2015-05-05T16:00:47.77+0300 [STG/0]      ERR                                  Dl
oad  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 16733  100 16733    0     0  28635      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 61745
2015-05-05T16:00:48.05+0300 [STG/0]      OUT Downloaded [https://pivotal-buildpa
cks.s3.amazonaws.com/php/binaries/lucid/httpd/2.4.12/httpd-mod_remoteip-2.4.12.t
ar.gz] to [/tmp]
2015-05-05T16:00:48.58+0300 [STG/0]      ERR   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Av
erage Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
2015-05-05T16:00:48.58+0300 [STG/0]      ERR                                  Dl
oad  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 12586  100 12586    0     0  23923      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 58813
2015-05-05T16:00:48.80+0300 [STG/0]      OUT Downloaded [https://pivotal-buildpa
cks.s3.amazonaws.com/php/binaries/lucid/httpd/2.4.12/httpd-mod_env-2.4.12.tar.gz
] to [/tmp]
2015-05-05T16:00:49.45+0300 [STG/0]      ERR   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Av
erage Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
2015-05-05T16:00:49.45+0300 [STG/0]      ERR                                  Dl
oad  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 61434  100 61434    0     0  72001      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  147k
2015-05-05T16:00:49.87+0300 [STG/0]      OUT Downloaded [https://pivotal-buildpa
cks.s3.amazonaws.com/php/binaries/lucid/httpd/2.4.12/httpd-mod_mpm_event-2.4.12.
tar.gz] to [/tmp]
2015-05-05T16:00:50.38+0300 [STG/0]      ERR   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Av
erage Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
2015-05-05T16:00:50.38+0300 [STG/0]      ERR                                  Dl
oad  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 67093  100 67093    0     0  89826      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  150k
2015-05-05T16:00:50.83+0300 [STG/0]      OUT Downloaded [https://pivotal-buildpa
cks.s3.amazonaws.com/php/binaries/lucid/httpd/2.4.12/httpd-mod_rewrite-2.4.12.ta
r.gz] to [/tmp]
2015-05-05T16:00:51.26+0300 [STG/0]      ERR   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Av
erage Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
2015-05-05T16:00:51.26+0300 [STG/0]      ERR                                  Dl
oad  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 14698  100 14698    0     0  43612      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  138k
2015-05-05T16:00:51.38+0300 [STG/0]      OUT Downloaded [https://pivotal-buildpa
cks.s3.amazonaws.com/php/binaries/lucid/httpd/2.4.12/httpd-mod_authz_host-2.4.12
.tar.gz] to [/tmp]
2015-05-05T16:00:51.41+0300 [STG/0]      OUT Installing PHP
2015-05-05T16:00:51.41+0300 [STG/0]      OUT PHP 5.4.39
2015-05-05T16:00:51.89+0300 [STG/0]      ERR   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Av
erage Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
2015-05-05T16:00:51.89+0300 [STG/0]      ERR                                  Dl
oad  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  279k  100  279k    0     0   266k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  378k
2015-05-05T16:00:52.64+0300 [STG/0]      OUT Downloaded [https://pivotal-buildpa
cks.s3.amazonaws.com/php/binaries/lucid/php/5.4.39/php-5.4.39.tar.gz] to [/tmp]
2015-05-05T16:00:53.15+0300 [STG/0]      ERR   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Av
erage Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
2015-05-05T16:00:53.15+0300 [STG/0]      ERR                                  Dl
oad  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 36564  100 36564    0     0  86631      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  198k
2015-05-05T16:00:53.34+0300 [STG/0]      OUT Downloaded [https://pivotal-buildpa
cks.s3.amazonaws.com/php/binaries/lucid/php/5.4.39/php-bz2-5.4.39.tar.gz] to [/t
mp]
2015-05-05T16:00:53.80+0300 [STG/0]      ERR   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Av
erage Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
2015-05-05T16:00:53.80+0300 [STG/0]      ERR                                  Dl
oad  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 8645k  100 8645k    0     0  4252k      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:-- 4800k
2015-05-05T16:00:55.63+0300 [STG/0]      OUT Downloaded [https://pivotal-buildpa
cks.s3.amazonaws.com/php/binaries/lucid/php/5.4.39/php-fpm-5.4.39.tar.gz] to [/t
mp]
2015-05-05T16:00:56.30+0300 [STG/0]      ERR   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Av
erage Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
2015-05-05T16:00:56.30+0300 [STG/0]      ERR                                  Dl
oad  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 55923  100 55923    0     0  95306      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  158k
2015-05-05T16:00:56.66+0300 [STG/0]      OUT Downloaded [https://pivotal-buildpa
cks.s3.amazonaws.com/php/binaries/lucid/php/5.4.39/php-zlib-5.4.39.tar.gz] to [/
tmp]
2015-05-05T16:00:57.10+0300 [STG/0]      ERR   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Av
erage Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
2015-05-05T16:00:57.10+0300 [STG/0]      ERR                                  Dl
oad  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  136k  100  136k    0     0   202k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  315k
2015-05-05T16:00:57.55+0300 [STG/0]      OUT Downloaded [https://pivotal-buildpa
cks.s3.amazonaws.com/php/binaries/lucid/php/5.4.39/php-openssl-5.4.39.tar.gz] to
 [/tmp]
2015-05-05T16:00:58.06+0300 [STG/0]      ERR   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Av
erage Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
2015-05-05T16:00:58.06+0300 [STG/0]      ERR                                  Dl
oad  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 63621  100 63621    0     0  90176      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  157k
2015-05-05T16:00:58.47+0300 [STG/0]      OUT Downloaded [https://pivotal-buildpa
cks.s3.amazonaws.com/php/binaries/lucid/php/5.4.39/php-mysql-5.4.39.tar.gz] to [
/tmp]
2015-05-05T16:00:58.98+0300 [STG/0]      ERR   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Av
erage Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
2015-05-05T16:00:58.98+0300 [STG/0]      ERR                                  Dl
oad  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  119k  100  119k    0     0   135k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  210k
2015-05-05T16:00:59.56+0300 [STG/0]      OUT Downloaded [https://pivotal-buildpa
cks.s3.amazonaws.com/php/binaries/lucid/php/5.4.39/php-mcrypt-5.4.39.tar.gz] to
[/tmp]
2015-05-05T16:01:00.01+0300 [STG/0]      ERR   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Av
erage Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
2015-05-05T16:01:00.01+0300 [STG/0]      ERR                                  Dl
oad  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 89587  100 89587    0     0   151k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  252k
2015-05-05T16:01:00.37+0300 [STG/0]      OUT Downloaded [https://pivotal-buildpa
cks.s3.amazonaws.com/php/binaries/lucid/php/5.4.39/php-curl-5.4.39.tar.gz] to [/
tmp]
2015-05-05T16:01:00.91+0300 [STG/0]      ERR   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Av
erage Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
2015-05-05T16:01:00.91+0300 [STG/0]      ERR                                  Dl
oad  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 8496k  100 8496k    0     0  3766k      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:-- 4379k
2015-05-05T16:01:02.89+0300 [STG/0]      OUT Downloaded [https://pivotal-buildpa
cks.s3.amazonaws.com/php/binaries/lucid/php/5.4.39/php-cli-5.4.39.tar.gz] to [/t
mp]
2015-05-05T16:01:03.68+0300 [STG/0]      ERR   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Av
erage Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
2015-05-05T16:01:03.68+0300 [STG/0]      ERR                                  Dl
oad  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1050k  100 1050k    0     0   684k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  856k
2015-05-05T16:01:04.92+0300 [STG/0]      OUT Downloaded [https://pivotal-buildpa
cks.s3.amazonaws.com/php/binaries/lucid/composer/1.0.0-alpha10/composer.phar] to
 [/tmp]
2015-05-05T16:01:04.92+0300 [STG/0]      OUT PROTIP: Include a `composer.lock` f
ile with your application! This will make sure the exact same version of depende
ncies are used when you deploy to CloudFoundry.
2015-05-05T16:01:05.23+0300 [STG/0]      ERR   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Av
erage Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
2015-05-05T16:01:05.23+0300 [STG/0]      ERR                                  Dl
oad  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
141   283  141   283    0     0    759      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2917
2015-05-05T16:01:05.49+0300 [STG/0]      ERR Loading composer repositories with
package information
2015-05-05T16:01:05.62+0300 [STG/0]      ERR Installing dependencies
2015-05-05T16:01:06.30+0300 [STG/0]      ERR Nothing to install or update
2015-05-05T16:01:06.30+0300 [STG/0]      ERR Generating autoload files
2015-05-05T16:01:06.37+0300 [STG/0]      OUT Finished: [2015-05-05 13:01:06.3788
81]
2015-05-05T16:01:10.61+0300 [STG/79]     OUT -----> Uploading droplet (20M)
2015-05-05T16:01:16.09+0300 [DEA/79]     OUT Starting app instance (index 0) wit
h guid 5196da19-69b9-4db3-abdc-c9219e919688
2015-05-05T16:01:23.17+0300 [App/0]      OUT     13:01:23 php-fpm | [05-May-2015
 13:01:23] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 40
2015-05-05T16:01:23.17+0300 [App/0]      OUT 13:01:23 php-fpm | [05-May-2015 13:
01:23] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
2015-05-05T16:01:23.20+0300 [App/0]      OUT 13:01:23 httpd   | [Tue May 05 13:0
1:23.201996 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 38:tid 140469691721472] AH00489: Apach
e/2.4.12 (Unix) configured -- resuming normal operations
2015-05-05T16:01:23.20+0300 [App/0]      OUT 13:01:23 httpd   | [Tue May 05 13:0
1:23.202201 2015] [mpm_event:info] [pid 38:tid 140469691721472] AH00490: Server
built: Mar  2 2015 15:40:43
2015-05-05T16:01:23.20+0300 [App/0]      OUT 13:01:23 httpd   | [Tue May 05 13:0
1:23.202225 2015] [core:notice] [pid 38:tid 140469691721472] AH00094: Command li
ne: '/home/vcap/app/httpd/bin/httpd -f /home/vcap/app/httpd/conf/httpd.conf -D F
OREGROUND'
2015-05-05T16:09:33.82+0300 [API/5]      OUT Updated app with guid 5196da19-69b9
-4db3-abdc-c9219e919688 ({"name"=>"testPHPbuild", "instances"=>1, "memory"=>128,
 "disk_quota"=>1024, "buildpack"=>"https://github.com/antonpuz/phpbuildpack.git"
, "environment_json"=>"PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN"})
2015-05-05T16:09:43.53+0300 [API/0]      OUT Updated app with guid 5196da19-69b9
-4db3-abdc-c9219e919688 ({"state"=>"STOPPED"})
2015-05-05T16:09:43.58+0300 [App/0]      ERR
2015-05-05T16:09:44.73+0300 [DEA/79]     OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) wit
h guid 5196da19-69b9-4db3-abdc-c9219e919688
2015-05-05T16:09:44.73+0300 [DEA/79]     OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with
 guid 5196da19-69b9-4db3-abdc-c9219e919688
2015-05-05T16:09:45.24+0300 [DEA/68]     OUT Got staging request for app with id
 5196da19-69b9-4db3-abdc-c9219e919688
2015-05-05T16:09:51.07+0300 [API/1]      OUT Updated app with guid 5196da19-69b9
-4db3-abdc-c9219e919688 ({"state"=>"STARTED"})
2015-05-05T16:09:51.21+0300 [STG/68]     OUT -----> Downloaded app package (20K)

2015-05-05T16:09:51.57+0300 [STG/68]     OUT -----> Downloaded app buildpack cac
he (7.7M)
2015-05-05T16:09:51.67+0300 [STG/0]      ERR     Cloning into '/tmp/buildpacks/p
hpbuildpack'...
2015-05-05T16:09:53.79+0300 [STG/0]      OUT     Staging failed: Buildpack compi
lation step failed
2015-05-05T16:09:53.98+0300 [API/1]      ERR Encountered error: App staging fail
ed in the buildpack compile phase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked your buildpack fork "https://github.com/antonpuz/phpbuildpack.git", and found that the detect, compile and release scripts in the bin folder does not have the executable bit. I guess you pushed these files from a Windows machine? Unfortunately when you do so, the executable bit is lost. You either need to change their attribute from 644 to 755 (e.g., from a Linux machine), or you can simply fork the original php buildpack by clicking "fork" in github directly, instead of pushing it from your local copy.

Comment: On a little delay but Thanks alot!

Comment: how did you check the permissions? simply ls -l from the console?

Comment: Yes, if you are on a Linux shell, do "ls -l" will show the file permissions, like below:

drwxr-xr-x    1 greensig Administ        0 Dec  9 14:21 trade
drwxr-xr-x    6 greensig Administ     4096 Apr 19  2014 worker

Answer (score 2):

The Heroku PHP buildpack is a little different than the CloudFoundry one.  With the Heroku buildpack, you may need to provide a `composer.json` file with your application. You can read more about it on their GitHub page: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php

Their detect script indicates that you must either have an `index.php` or `composer.json` file in the root directory of your application.

There may also be other differences in the buildpack causing your compile phase to fail.  You can try to inspect the recent logs from your application to see if it offers any clues.  Try doing `cf logs app_name --recent`.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer, the second buildpack I tried is a direct copy of the cloudfoundry PHP buildpack and it doesnt work also, I included the log, unfortunately I cant understand anything from it. Any ideas on might gone wrong there?

Comment: Taking a quick look at the log looks like you have a PHP Parse error: `PHP Parse error: syntax error, u nexpected '$conn' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';' in /home/vcap/app/htdocs/in dex.php on line 16`